# Manual added routes and rules in Network manager

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I added a few static routes and rules with command `ip route add ...` and `ip rule add ...`. Now I want to make the configuration persistent after reboots. The system is managed by Network Manager.

Is there a command in `nmcli` to retrieve the current live route/rule configuration and save it to Network Manager configuration files?

Alternatively, is there another method to persist the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a command in nmcli to get the live route/rule configuration and store it to Network Manager configuration files?

There is not.

> Or is there another approach to persist the configuration?

Create your custom routes and rules using NetworkManager rather than using the `ip` commands. Instead of:

```
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 via 10.10.10.1
```

You can run (assuming this is for a connection named `enp1s0`):

```
nmcli connection modify enp1s0 +ipv4.routes "192.168.122.0/24 10.10.10.1"
```

You can do the same thing with rules; instead of running:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.122.0/24 table 1000
```

You can run:

```
nmcli connection modify enps10 +ipv4.routing-rules "from 192.168.122.0/24 table 1000"
```

See [1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_static_routes_using_nmcli) and [2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-policy-based-routing-to-define-alternative-routes_configuring-and-managing-networking) for documentation.

Comment: Is it necessary to delete routes and rules added with ip command to avoid duplicate entries in live configuration?

Comment: Probably; failure to do so might result in duplicate rules. Of course, when you reboot the system, the routes/rules added via `ip` will be gone in any case.

Comment: Just fyi: when a route or rule is added with nmcli commands in the answer and the same route or rule already exists in the live configuration then the route/rule is added to NM config only and duplicate entry in life config is not created.